# Setting environment variables in Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a small node.js application that accepts POST requests and would upload the data to Google BigQuery.

BigQuery requires the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to be set, else BigQuery will just timeout. As explained here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

For example, making the query when the server was started as the following works as intended:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/credentials.json DEBUG=* bin/www
```

Making the query when the server was started as the following produces a timeout:

```
DEBUG=* bin/www
```

I've tried the following npm packages to set environment variables within the script:

```
"envs": "0.1.6",
"dotenv": "5.0.1"
```

And setting them as:

```
var envs = require('envs');
app.set('environment', envs('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS', 'path/to/credentials.json'));
```

and

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

but alas...

Google Cloud function does not allow me to specify any environment variables, the script deployment logic is all behind the scenes. I've tried locating the config file in Google Cloud Console, and thought of setting it as a global environment variable, but I can't even locate it in that console.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edit 08/14/2018**

There was no option to set environment variables, but it's available now in beta mode. Just use the next command on deploy:

```
cloud beta functions deploy YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME --set-env-vars VAR1=foo,VAR2=bar FLAGS
```

**edit 11/22/2018**  (per Martin Omander's suggestion)

You can also set them from your node.js code if that makes sense for you:
    process.env.MY_VARIABLE = "it_works"

**old answer (with resolution for the actual problem not related to env variables)**

Unfortunately unlike AWS Lambda SCF doesn't support setting environment variables, at least in some obvious way.

But in your case you actually don't need that. You need GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS on your local environment for testing, but on google cloud function it's enough to just set the project id in case you're using BigQuery npm

```
const BigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const projectId = 'project-id';

exports.testBigQuery = (req, res) => {

   const bigquery = new BigQuery({
       projectId: projectId,
   });


   bigquery
      .createDataset('test_set')
      .then(results => {
          const dataset = results[0];
          res.send(dataset.id);
      })
      .catch(err => {
          console.error('ERROR:', err);
      });
};
```

Comment: How sure are you that that's the case? Because that's exactly what I'm doing. Both bigquery and the Cloud Funcion part of the same project, and I'm getting the same timeout error as when locally testing without GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.

Comment: I'm sure because I did that myself and it worked for me without manually setting any credentials. I've updated my answer with actual test code that I successfully run on my GCF account. Your timeout is probably caused by some other issue. Can you share the source of your function? Also since GCF are beta they are still a bit raw, and there are cases when removing your function and turning cloud functions on and off for you account can resolve such issues. If your code is ok you should try that.

Comment: My code should be ok, it's been in use for a few weeks (just a proxy for parsing location data and forwarding it), just now moving it to GCF. I could share it, sure, but it's a bit odd doing it in the comments section here. And thanks, I'll try turning it off and on again!

Comment: Update: After creating a new function and moving bigquery initialization into exports, it seems to be working. Rows are inserted, but still getting the timeout, however, after completion

Comment: great! Since rows are being inserted it looks like timeout isn't cause by BigQuery, so it's probably caused by function not exiting properly. You need to explicitly end function execution. In my example it's done by returning dataset.id using res object: res.send(dataset.id); You can also use .end() method

Comment: Thank you for posting this clear and informative answer, Sasha! You can also set environment variables from Google Cloud Functions code. Node.js example: process.env.MY_VARIABLE = "it_works". Would you please update this part of your answer?